# адаптивная сетка flex-box

Tags: css, flexbox

Всем привет. Подскажите как зафиксировать ширину background для адаптивной сетки?
Вот как должны выглядеть карточки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при уменьшении экрана мне нужно чтобы они становились по две, что я делаю с помощью стилей:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 996px) {
 .prices__col{
   width: calc(100% / 12 * 4 - 15px);
 }
```

}

Но блин background растягивается а мне нужно чтобы он всегда был не больше изображения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это сделать?

Вот весь код:

```css
.row__prices{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.prices__col{
    width: calc(23% - 15px);
    margin: 0 15px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 996px){
    .prices__col{
        width: calc(100% / 12 * 4 - 15px);
    }
}
.prices__item{
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 60deg, rgb(134,227,62) 0%, rgb(22,215,122) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 60deg, rgb(134,227,62) 0%, rgb(22,215,122) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 60deg, rgb(134,227,62) 0%, rgb(22,215,122) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
 
.prices__item-text{
    padding: 15px 30px;
}
.prices__btn{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 13px 0;
    width: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 20px auto 0px;
    display: block;
    color: #b2b2b2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row__prices">
 
                <div class="prices__col">
 
                    <div class="prices__item">
                        <div class="prices__item-img">
                            <img src="img/prises-cart/prise-cart-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="prices__item-text">
                            <h4>Электрические шторы</h4>
                            <p>SOMFY 1</p>
                            <p>цена: от <span>2000</span> руб.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="prices__btn">рассчитать</a>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>      
                
                <div class="prices__col">
                    
                    <div class="prices__item">
                        <div class="prices__item-img">
                            <img src="img/prises-cart/prise-cart-2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="prices__item-text">
                            <h4>Электрические шторы</h4>
                            <p>SOMFY 1</p>
                            <p>цена: от <span>2000</span> руб.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="prices__btn">рассчитать</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
 
                <div class="prices__col">
                    
                    <div class="prices__item">
                        <div class="prices__item-img">
                            <img src="img/prises-cart/prise-cart-3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="prices__item-text">
                            <h4>Электрические шторы</h4>
                            <p>SOMFY 1</p>
                            <p>цена: от <span>2000</span> руб.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="prices__btn">рассчитать</a>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>  
 
                <div class="prices__col">
                    
                    <div class="prices__item">
                        <div class="prices__item-img">
                            <img src="img/prises-cart/prise-cart-4.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="prices__item-text">
                            <h4>Электрические шторы</h4>
                            <p>SOMFY 1</p>
                            <p>цена: от <span>2000</span> руб.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="prices__btn">рассчитать</a>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Блин ну я даю!) Нашел решение     max-width: 263px; (это ширина изображения) для .prices__item

Comment: Ну тогда посмотрите пожалуйста на саму сетку нормальна сделана или слишком нахимичил?

Comment: в `.prices__col` замените свой `margin: 0 15px` на `margin: 15px 15px`. Так красивее будет )

Comment: А не лучше размеры картинки "резиново" подстраивать под размеры контейнера, а не наооборт?